# Starting with Spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I'm planning to start learning Spring but when I open any spring tutorial, I find many modules like Spring REST, spring MVC etc.

I'm really confused on how to start with spring, from which module to start, how are these modules related to each other, should I go through all the modules??

I tried searching many sites to answer my questions but couldn't find satisfactory ans, so thought of posting here. It would be great if somebody can guide me in this regard.

Comment: I'd read the official documentation. If you told us what kind of application you plan to create, we could give you hints.

Comment: I think that you can start, learning first how Depency Injection & IoC works, how spring born, what problems they try to solve, there is a large debate about Spring vs EJB.

Comment: @ JB Nizet : Thanks for your comment.
Official documentation has got links to many modules. I'm not sure from which link to start. 
I dont have any particular application in mind. If you can suggest which module of Spring is widely used I can go with that.
I'm having knowledge of Java, JQuery, Angular JS, MVC design pattern.

Comment: Some small but super useful guides to get you started can be found [here](http://spring.io/guides)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring is a java framework which provides solutions to several problems. So i guess it really depends on what you are planning to learn. The most important to learn first is understanding what Dependency Injection and inversion of control means. When you understand this you will understand why the rest of the frameworks are designed as it is. i suppose learn Spring IoC first since this is basically the core component of Spring Framework. Link: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

After learning Spring IoC, you can go on learning each specific Spring frameworks which address specific problems. For example:

```
Are you interested in Web development? --> Spring MVC
Are you interested in storing data to database? --> Spring Data
Are you interested in developing web services / web apis --> Spring REST
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html

Comment: Just what I needed :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Start with Spring Core Module, which is the heart of entire Spring.**

> Spring Core Module helps in Injecting Dependencies (java objects) into
>   the Application at Runtime.

Please refer below URL for more details:

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/core-concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

A good knowledge of design patterns is essential for learning any framework in Java.

These [Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC97BDEFDCDD169D7) can give you a good understanding of basic Spring.

As explained in the previous answers, start learning with the Spring core. You need to have a sound knowledge of servlets, JSP, Hibernate (ORM's) to understand the advanced topics.